# Nesting CSS issue

Tags: css

I created fiddle to show the example: I think I am setting parent CSS and then I apply the child's CSS. But it seems like it is being ignored.

http://jsfiddle.net/8PWNw/2/

```
<div id="displaybox" class ="displaybox" style="display: none;">
    <div class = "parent" >
        <a href="reply.php?id=1">Parent 1</a>
    </div>
    <span  class ="child"  style="padding: 0 10 "><a href="reply.php?id=3">Child 1</a></span>
    <div class = "parent" >
        <a href="reply.php?id=2">Parent 2</a>
    </div>
    <span  class ="child"  style="padding: 0 10 "><a href="reply.php?id=4">Child 1</a></span>
</div>
```

Please advise. I am new to CSS, so there are many things that I need learn.

Comment: This is how you make a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8PWNw/2/ ;)

Comment: thank you; I don't know why, but it was saying `no class defined'; do I just dumped the whole page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 23 in your CSS:

```
/* this is actually saying element with both 'parent' and 'a' class */

    .displaybox .parent.a {
        color: black; 
    }
```

You probably meant:

```
/* this is actually saying all 'A' elements within element with 'parent' class */

    .displaybox .parent a {
        color: black; 
    }
```

That is why your 'A' element style is being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

`padding: 0 10` isn't valid (use a [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)) so browsers are required to ignore it.

Lengths, other than zero, must have units (such as `px` or `em`).

You shouldn't be able to tell this though, since `display: none` hides everything.

Comment: display; is just a popup -- please check the fiddle. I try to show it in different colors, but it does not show.

Comment: *please check the fiddle* — Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and include a  *complete* question on StackOverflow, preferably one that works as a reduced test case - unless the `display: none` is having an impact on the problem, don't include it.

Answer (score 0):

Your class displaybox is set on `display: none`, which basically hides the entire container.

On another note, you use classes parent-child, but your children aren't nested properly into their parents. You need to put them before the end `</div>` tags so they be a part of that container.

I edited your fiddle and this should work now: http://jsfiddle.net/8PWNw/

This is what I changed:

I removed the `display:none` so your displaybox is shown again. I then changed some CSS:

Changed this, because your syntax didn't work before. The "." indicates you're addressing a class, in this case class displaybox with a child class parent, and you want to address all a elements in that class.

```
.displaybox .parent a
{
    color: black; 
}
```

I also added this one so you're links are showing as white:

```
.child a 
{
    color: white;
}
```

With those changes, you should be able to get it working like you want.